# Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2190): x

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, graph, analysis

```
structure(list(Generation = c(1, 2, 3, 4), Type = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Mean_1", "Mean_16", "Mean_4", "Mean_64", 
"Mean_F"), class = "factor"), Heterozygosity = c(0.983622406756008, 
0.984560911429398, 0.984607962819721, 0.983946353837307)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So I have a data frame with the above structure, which looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Generation Type   Heterozygosity
       <dbl> <fct>           <dbl>
1          1 Mean_1          0.984
2          2 Mean_1          0.985
3          3 Mean_1          0.985
4          4 Mean_1          0.984
5          5 Mean_1          0.983
6          6 Mean_1          0.983
```

and I'm trying to plot a line graph with the following code:

```
ggplot(LongRed, aes(x = Generations, y = Heterozygosity)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = Type))
```

and it gives me the error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2190): x
```

What should I do?

Comment: Your column name is 'Generation'. If I change it to that, it is working fine for me with the dput data

Answer (score 0):

It is working with 'Generation' instead of 'Generations'

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(LongRed, aes(x = Generation, y = Heterozygosity)) + 
      geom_line(aes(color = Type))
```

[image]